# Rspec raise error not working as expected, need correct syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm testing a class raises an error

```
context 'with no office manager' do
      let(:expected_response) do
        {
            error: "No office manager"
        }
      end
      it 'returns an error' do
        expect{ subject.run }.to raise_exception(an_instance_of(StandardError).and having_attributes(expected_response))
      end
    end
```

Gets the failed test response:

```
expected Exception with an instance of StandardError and having attributes {:error => "No office manager"}, got #<StandardError: {:error=>"No office manager"}>
```

What's the correct syntax to make this pass?

Comment: I can see that way is documented in the [docs](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher), but I can't see it's in the code (at least in the master branch), maybe is not available anymore, or maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say that's not so *common* to pass an object to an exception more than a string to hint the one that's reading it (or maybe also the `caller`). But if you want to check that, you can try passing a block to `raise_error` and expect the block argument `message` method is equal to the second argument for `raise`:

```
RSpec.describe 'raise plus a non-string second argument' do
  context 'with no office manager' do
    let(:expected_response) do
      { error: 'No office manager' }
    end

    it 'returns an error' do
      expect do
        raise StandardError, expected_response
      end.to raise_error(StandardError) { |error| expect(error.message).to eq expected_response.to_s }
    end
  end
end
```

Notice, `raise_error` and `raise_exception` are functionally interchangeable, so, you can use the one that
makes the most sense to you in any given context.

Answer (score 1):

An exception in Ruby has a [`#message`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Exception.html#method-i-message) method/attribute, but not `#error`. So you need to change

```
let(:expected_response) do
  {
    error: "No office manager"
  }
end
```

to

```
let(:expected_response) do
  {
    message: "No office manager"
  }
end
```